# 12.04.2 - after the last update my qualcomm atheros gigabit ethernet driver is lost

Tags: 12.04, ethernet, atheros

after the last update the driver is lost. 
I have tried hard (several nights) to get it running.
Now with the last update it's gone.
Any thoughts why this is not supported natively?
What is the best way to get it back?

Comment: please press Ctrl-Alt-t, in the terminal, run: `lspci -vv | grep Atheros`, edit your question and post output of that command. Also:  Do you have internet access through wifi?

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.4-precise-generic
```

then

```
sudo modprobe alx
```

I hope you have internet access through wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but when I installed 12.04.2 from disk, the Atheros 8161
ethernet card was not working due to the alx driver missing.

I did the following to get it to work:

1. `apt-get update`
2. `apt-get upgrade`

   The following packages have been kept back:

   linux-image-3.5.0-27-generic
   linux-headers-3.5.0-27-generic
3. `sudo aptitude`

If you have kept back package you should see Upgradable Packages on top of the list.

- Hit + on that list
- Hit g twice
- Answer debconf stuff if asked
- Press <kbd>Return</kbd> to continue
- Press <kbd>Q</kbd>
- Type yes